# Auto select <option> added to <select>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I add "option"s to "select" with javascript or jquery.

I would like to select last added  and scroll the scrollbar to most bottom.

i add text like this

```
function ConsoleOutputAdd(text){
    var content = '<option>'+ text +'</option>';
    $consoleoutput.append(content); 
}
```

this is the select element.

```
<select id="consoleoutput" size="4">></select>
```

i think it would be with onchanged event but i cant think anything more.

thank you

Comment: Have you considered using a different control to display the output, such as a `<textarea>`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#consoleoutput').find('option:last').prop('selected', true );
```

[Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/azizpunjani/NJ4Tx/) a fiddle

Answer (score 2):

You can select the last item in the list like so:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('consoleoutput');
sel.selectedIndex = sel.options.length - 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

1: write an on-change listener to your select element

```
$('#consoleoutput').change(function(){
   // scroll
})
```

2: add this to select the option you have added:

```
$("#consoleoutput").val(text);
```

Comment: The `change` event isn't fired when you add an `<option>` element to the `<select>` element, though, so I'm not really sure what this answer is supposed to achieve.

Comment: it should be triggered when the most recently added option is selected (programatically), by with .val()

Comment: Hoff, actually it's not triggered when you programatically set the value, it's only triggered when you manually select another option.